# map through object of objects to return object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I tried looking into other examples but I am not getting it.
I am trying to loop through obj of objects and return an object with key value pair.

```
const res =  {0 : {id: "id1", name: "name1" , rollno: "1"}, 1 : {id: "id2", name: "name2", rollno: "2"}}

const section = {"id1" : "section A", "id3" : "section B"}

const result = Object.entries(res).map((item) => ({id: item.id, name: item.name, section: section.[item.id]})).  // failing

//expected result = {0 : {id: "id1", name: "name1" , section: "section A"}, 1 : {id: "id2", name: "name2", section: "undefined"}}
```

Comment: Just replace `Object.entries()` with `Object.values()`. Also, it should be `section: section[item.id]` without the `.` before `[]`.

Comment: Why is `res` an object with numerical indices? Why is it not an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because **Object.entries** returns an array containing the key and the value of the object you passed.

So instead of:

```
Object.entries(res).map((item)
```

You need to do:

```
Object.entries(res).map(([key, item])
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey you just have to add dynamic key values to object.

```js
const res = {
  0: { id: "id1", name: "name1", rollno: "1" },
  1: { id: "id2", name: "name2", rollno: "2" },
};

const section = { id1: "section A", id2: "section B" };

let result = Object.entries(res).map((item, index) => {
  return  { [index]: {
    id: item[1].id,
    name: item[1].name,
    section: section[item[1].id],
  }} 
});
console.log(result);
```